# MediaSourceExtension fMP4 streaming playback fail

Tags: html, media-source

Following [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/11/Stream-video-using-the-MediaSource-API) link, I just change the webm format to fMP4 as below. But it doesn't work. The original test.webm file works fine.

for webm, the config as below:

```
//source: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/test.webm
var FILE = "test.webm"
var codec = 'video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"';
```

for fMP4, change the config as below:

```
//source http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/car-20120827-85.mp4
var FILE = "car-20120827-85.mp4";
var codec = 'video/mp4; codecs="mp4a,avc"';
//var codec = 'video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2,avc1.640028"';
```

I guess the mime for fMP4 maybe wrong but I can not figure out it after many search from internet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<section>
  <video controls autoplay width="320" height="240"></video>
  <pre id="log"></pre>
</section>
<script>
//source: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/test.webm
//var FILE = "test.webm"
//var codec = 'video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"';

//source http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/car-20120827-85.mp4
var FILE = "car-20120827-85.mp4";
var codec = 'video/mp4; codecs="mp4a,avc"';
//var codec = 'video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2,avc1.640028"';

var NUM_CHUNKS = 5;
var video = document.querySelector('video');

window.MediaSource = window.MediaSource || window.WebKitMediaSource;
if (!!!window.MediaSource) {
  alert('MediaSource API is not available');
}

var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

function callback(e) {
  var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(codec);

  logger.log('mediaSource readyState: ' + this.readyState);

  GET(FILE, function(uInt8Array) {
    var file = new Blob([uInt8Array], {type: 'video/webm'});
    var chunkSize = Math.ceil(file.size / NUM_CHUNKS);

    logger.log('num chunks:' + NUM_CHUNKS);
    logger.log('chunkSize:' + chunkSize + ', totalSize:' + file.size);

    // Slice the video into NUM_CHUNKS and append each to the media element.
    var i = 0;

    (function readChunk_(i) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Reads aren't guaranteed to finish in the same order they're started in,
      // so we need to read + append the next chunk after the previous reader
      // is done (onload is fired).
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(e.target.result));
        logger.log('appending chunk:' + i);
        if (i == NUM_CHUNKS - 1) {
          mediaSource.endOfStream();
        } else {
          if (video.paused) {
            video.play(); // Start playing after 1st chunk is appended.
          }
          readChunk_(++i);
        }
      };

      var startByte = chunkSize * i;
      var chunk = file.slice(startByte, startByte + chunkSize);

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
    })(i);  // Start the recursive call by self calling.
  });
}

mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', callback, false);
mediaSource.addEventListener('webkitsourceopen', callback, false);

mediaSource.addEventListener('webkitsourceended', function(e) {
  logger.log('mediaSource readyState: ' + this.readyState);
}, false);

function GET(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.send();

  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
      alert("Unexpected status code " + xhr.status + " for " + url);
      return false;
    }
    callback(new Uint8Array(xhr.response));
  };
}
</script>
<script>
function Logger(id) {
  this.el = document.getElementById('log');
}
Logger.prototype.log = function(msg) {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  this.el.appendChild(fragment);
};

var logger = new Logger('log');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `fMP4` is a different format than `webm`. While you can split a `webm` file in chunks defined arbitrarily, you can't do so with `fMP4`.

The `fMP4` file is just a bunch of "boxes" which are basically structures with a `type`, `length` and `content` (which can contain other boxes, making it hierarchical). You must parse the file and give the sourceBuffer a `moov` box first (an initialization segment), and then a sequence of `moof mdat` boxes that can be decoded and played out.

You probably have to read a bit on the `fMP4` format (aka `ISO BMFF`).

Comment: Thanks, so fMP4 actually can not be used as live streaming since user maybe start playback at any point. only VOD use case will get the file header. How about save the header box then send it firstly if use playback from the middle of the file?

Comment: That's exactly what you do in case you want to do live streaming...you save the `moov` box to be sent as initialization segment, and then send the `moof+mdat` segments. You have to move the `currentTime` of the `video` element you are using to play, as the fragments you are playing back will have > 0 PTS.

Comment: Thanks, Can I just modify the moov box to add a timeOffset? Or I have to alter every moof box to change current time?

Comment: Mmm...probably, but too much work for little gain. You can know the time of the buffered segments (in JavaScript), so you just make sure once you have buffered a segment, that the `currentTime` on the player matches that which was buffered and start playback.